# What are the common techniques to solve this type of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found this series:

$2;10;32;88$

My teacher has told me that there is no methodology or equation to find the n-term ( Im be in high school yet ).

It really is that? If so, at least there are techniques? It takes a lot of time to do the test-error, thinking practically at random.

Things like this:

$-2;4;-6;8$ can be solved more easy, because is a it is a more concordant pattern.

= $2n(-1)^n$ ( With $a_1$ as first index)

Comment: In fact things are worse, there is no unique series defined by just giving four terms. One can concoct rules to extend that in very many ways. Usually what is expected is the simplest pattern, but that is a bit subjective.

Comment: Who is to say that the fifth term of your sequence $-2,4,-6,8$ was actually going to be $-10$?  It could have just as easily continued as $-2,4,-6,8,1,7,\dots$.  Indeed, **every** "find the next number in the sequence" questions are flawed in this way.  The only way to have a unique answer is if the question asker tells you information about the sequence itself, such as "it must be one of the following sequence types: geometric, arithmetic, or linear" and even then it might not be enough information.

Comment: Even the seemingly innocent start to a sequence "$1,2,3,4,5$" has [thousands of entries corresponding to it](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5&language=english&go=Search) on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: @JMoravitz That's for sure, although one could argue that most of these questions implicitely state that the formula comes from an elementary function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You like to fit these values $$(1,2);(2,10);(3,32);(4,88)$$ into a model.

While there are many different ways to find such a model, it is easy to find a polynomial to fit the data.

Check the following model:

$$a_n=(44/3)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)-16(n-1)(n-2)(n-4)+5(n-1)(n-3)(n-4)-(1/3) (n-2)(n-3)(n-4)$$

The simplified polynomial takes the form $$ a_n=\frac {1}{3}(10n^3-39n^2+71n-36)$$
Your data fits perfectly in this model.

Note that the answer is not unique because there are many curves passing through your data.

Comment: But is soo big, how simplify ?

Comment: You can do the algebra and add similar terms to write it as a simple polynomial of degree 3. Check my edited version.

Comment: Wow, why you write it like a (x, y)??

Comment: This requires calculus? I'm only in school

Comment: Algebra is all that you need. Polynomials are studies in  algebra.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Why you use (x,y) ??

Comment: your x values are 1,2,3,4 because you have 4 numbers and your y values are the terms in your  sequence. The way you do it is that consider  a polynomial $ an^3+bn^2+cn+d$ and find a,b,c,d such that for n=1 you get the first term and for n=2 you get the second term and so on.

Comment: You get 44/3 of sum 2 + 10 + 32 + 88, but why ? And how you get b = 16, c = 5

Comment: you can explain how you get that polynomial? detailed please

Comment: @Mattiu the technique is called [Lagrangian Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) and the wiki link has plenty of information on it.  The point is that when you plug in $n=1,2,3$ or $4$, any term with a factor of $(n-1),(n-2),(n-3)$ or $(n-4)$ will disappear respectively.  E.g. if you plug in $n=1$ the only surviving term will be the one without $(n-1)$, i.e. the term $\color{red}{k}(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)$.  We then pick the value of $\color{red}{k}$ to be the appropriate value to get what we want for the first term in the desired sequence, in this case $-\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: And how you get the -1/3

Comment: I already can understand the (n-1)(n-2) but how the number is obtained ?

Comment: In a video says that is(in this case) : $2/(n_0 - n_1)$, but how this will be -1/3 ?

Comment: And what values will be n_0 and n_1 ?

Comment: Mm studying, now i think that is: $\frac{2}{(1-2)(1-3)(1-4)}$ is CORRECT?

Comment: wow works fine, but how you factoring it? you use some special factorization?

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is right. There is no general method for finding the $n$th term of a sequence when you know just the first few. There are infinitely many continuations, and it may well happen that more than one of them is interesting, or correct in some particular context.

You might have fun browsing at The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: https://oeis.org/ . Your's isn't there. Where did it come from? If you discovered it in some mathematical exploration perhaps you should tell OEIS about it.